# WPF Application cannot work all of a sudden

Tags: wpf, vb.net, exception, crash, xamlparseexception

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in 
>       PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Set property
>       'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.

I get this `error` whenever I try to debug my application. I haven't touched it for a few days and when i left it alone, it was still working, all of a sudden after yesterday I tried and it doesn't work. I even tried it on another computer, which had downloaded my application when it was working too and suprisingly it doesnt work too. I cannot run it or it will crash. Please help!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19001218/1648849) helpful for you?

Comment: Hi, the solution doesnt work for me. There is no add-in security option for me.

Comment: I doubt that anyone can answer your question the way it is. I think you should provide more details or some code so that we can reproduce the exception. I suggest line by line debugging (F10) to find out which line exactly is raising the exception.

Comment: I am very sure it is not my code, as it was working fine and I havent touched it since, but can you tell me how can I check if it is an auto load add-in or extensions? Since I did configure my Windows yesterday but I am not sure which process broke it.