# Inconsistent Line Endings Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio

In 2015 you could change this from File -> Advanced Save, however this is no longer a menu option.

Where is it located now? I mean the option to actually change what the line endings are, not disable the message.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Click:

**Save As**

Click the drop arrow next to **Save**.

Select **Save with Encoding**:

[image: Save with Encoding]

Now you can set the line endings:

[image: Line endings]