# Visual Studio - How to save files in ASCII (2017)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I used to be able to convince the Visual Studio editor to save my source files in plain old 8 bit ascii, no BOM. I think all I had to do was set project->properties->configuration properties->Character Set to "Not Set". That was then. Now it's Visual Studio 2017, and I cannot figure out a way to do it.

QUESTION: How?

I have tried setting that properties value to "inherit from parent ...". I also tried typing in "ascii".  It accepts that value, but it has no effect.

EDIT - I figured it out. See the answer I posted.

Comment: Since when did "project->properties->configuration properties->Character Set" set the encoding of the current file in the editor?

Comment: @Dai - I don't know. Do you think there was a time when it did not? All that matters to me is what it does now.

Comment: I don't see "Configuration properties" anywhere in my Visual Studio installation. If you're referring to the "Character set" property in C++ projects then that refers to the runtime library's handling of text, not how files are saved in the editor.

Comment: @Dai - Now I am confused again, and I thank you for that. Somehow back in the day, I got VS to save files in us-ascii, and I don't know how I did it. See the revision of the question. I'm giving you a well-earned +1, but still longing for the old days.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623731/what-is-the-default-encoding-for-source-files-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to save in ASCII and not UTF-8 (with or without the BOM)?

Comment: @Dai - No good reason probably. I do not know much about this subject. Is it the case that utf-8 (no bom) is identical to ascii if the file only contains ascii characters?

Comment: Correct, UTF-8 is binary-compatible with ASCII (7-bit characters).

Comment: @Dia - Thanks. I winkled the solution out of the web. Your questions helped.

Answer (score 3):

File > Save As > Save with Encoding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this does what I want. (If the file contains only ASCII chars (7 bit), then utf-8 (not utf-8-bom) is identical to ASCII. I am sure I knew that at one time, but old folks forget things.)

Here's what to do...

Download an extension: [Editor Config Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.EditorConfig)...  Close Visual Studio and install the extension.

Re-start VS, and open the solution. Open Solution Explorer. Right click on the solution, and click Add. At the bottom of the list, click editorconfig file.

Click on Solution Items/editorconfig to edit it.

In the section [*], add the following

```
charset = utf-8
```

Initially, mine looked like this:

```
[*]
end_of_line = crlf
charset = utf-8

[*.xml]
indent_style = space
```