# Problems with UTF-8 without BOM, ASP MVC 5 project, does not display special characters well

Tags: asp.net-mvc, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I'm just trying to create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Visual Studio 2017. The files created by VS are encoded in UTF8 but without BOM.

After creating the new project using the VS template, if I just add one special character to one page and run the project, the character is not displayed correctly by my browsers. `é` looks like `Ã©` for example.

I used to develop with VS2013, and the files were encoded in UTF8 **with** BOM.

I made some search and I saw that's a good thing to remove the BOM from file as it's seems to be unnecessary.

I read that I should add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` (html5) or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` (previous versions of html) to tell to the browser that the content of the page is UTF-8, but these tags are already present in the layout of the template website created by VS, but it's still not working.

Do I miss something?

Does a charset "utf8-without-bom" exists?

Comment: You probably want to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49623731/11683

Comment: Thanks, i choose to set charset to utf-8-bom in the .editorconfig, it's working well now.