# How to open file in Visual Studio editor using proper encoding?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, character-encoding, idl

I have a .idl file with some extended non-ASCII characters in the comments using Windows-1252 encoding.  When I open it in the IDE editor I get an error message:

> Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file xxx.idl with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding. Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents.

Sure enough, the special characters have been replaced with the question mark in a black diamond.

When I do a compile, the file is automatically resaved with the garbage characters in it.  The characters are only in comments, so everything compiles just fine, but the comments are ruined.  The source control system notices the change and helpfully offers to check in the bad file, which would make the damage permanent.

I've tried to find a way to get Visual Studio to open the file with the proper encoding but haven't found a suitable setting anywhere.  I found this Microsoft documentation [/source-charset (Set Source Character Set)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/source-charset-set-source-character-set?view=vs-2019) but apparently it only affects the compiler, not the editor.

Is there a setting, hopefully file-by-file but more globally would be OK too, where I can specify the character encoding?

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't find any options specific to the MIDL compiler, only general C++ ones.  But it's not the compiler I worry about, it's the editor.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft.

Comment: @jkb I don't consider needing "Open With" every time I open a file to be an acceptable solution.  For example, if I get a compile error I should be able to double-click on the error to open the file to the line causing the error.

Comment: You can try EditorConfig https://stackoverflow.com/a/49643621/84507

Comment: @SergeyVlasov thanks for the suggestion.  It looks like it would work, but I haven't managed to create a file that makes any difference.

Comment: I am afraid there is no setting to set encoding file-by-file.

Comment: @BarrnetChou that was my conclusion too, but I was hoping there was someone out there who knows better than either of us.  I can't even find a global setting.