# Can't open dsw file in Visual Studio C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, mfc, newline, visual-studio-6

When I try to "Open Workplace" of my project, visual studio does nothing, solution explorer is empty.
Also when I try to open my project, I occasionally see this error:

[image: This makefile was not generated by Developer Studio. Continuing will create a new Developer Studio project to wrap this makefile. You will be prompted to save after the new project has been created. Do you want to continue?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my dsp/dsw file endings were LF. You can check your file endings in your code editor or using this git command:

```
git ls-files --eol
```

After converting ds/dsp files to CRLF, I was able to open the project.
You can convert file endings in Unix using this command:

```
unix2dos YouFileName.dsw
```

Comment: [You may be able to automate this conversion process.](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Comment: I don't know if this applies in VC6 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323941/inconsistent-line-endings-visual-studio-community-2017/43324108#43324108). Could you manually open the file in VC (as opposed to opening a workspace specifically) and adjust the line endings using this approach?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think you can. But sometimes when I change line endings and then stage the changes git status says 'working tree clean', even though it saw changed line endings before I staged them

Comment: I see. But since you know it changed you could do a force push.

Comment: the problem is git doesnt see it as a change. there is nothing to commit and therefore push